# using std::transform for calling object's function

Tags: c++, stl, lambda, boost-bind

Suppose I have a vector of shared pointers of objects of class A. I want to collect all the return values of method A::foo for all of the A objects and store them in some container, say another vector.
Can this be done with `std::transform` or `std::for_each` and `std::bind` or some `boost` function ?

```
class A {

  public:
  string foo(int p);

};

std::vector<shared_ptr<A>> vec;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is fine for this:

```
std::vector<std::string> string_vec;
const int magic_number = 42;
std::transform(std::begin(vec),
              std::end(vec),
              std::back_inserter(string_vec),
              [magic_number](std::shared_ptr<A> a){ return a->foo(magic_number); } );
```

Obviously, you need to figure out which `int` you want to pass to `A::foo(int)`.

In C++03, you can replace the lambda by a functor or function:

```
struct get_foo
{
  get_foo(int n) : n_(n) {}
  bool operator() (std::shared_ptr<A> a) const { return a->foo(n); }
private:
  int n_;
};

const int magic_number = 42;
std::vector<std::string> string_vec;
std::transform(std::begin(vec),
              std::end(vec),
              std::back_inserter(string_vec),
              get_foo(magic_number));
```

Comment: If you need to pass in multiple different values to the `a->foo` call, you will want to create a functor instead of using a lambda function so you can store the state as you move through them.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was looking for ways for older version of c++ without lambda, can this be done with bind and available stl functors without defining our own custom functons taking vec's iterator.

Comment: @ZacHowland another option would be to put the values in another vector, and use the binary functor overload of `std::transform`. But given the sparsity of details in the question, I guess `42` is a good number to use.

Comment: @user124 Sure, you can write a functor or even a simple function. You should specify in your question where you want to get the `int` values for `foo()` from.

Comment: sorry for confusion about arguments. Argument to foo would remain same throughout the range of vec, say 42. A's type object returns different strings depending upon their state, A is kind of base class, and we have vector of A's objects. While searching, I stumble upon std::bind and std::transform function which are used in similar scenarios of calling functions, so thought if this can also be done using them...say in one line, instead of writing several lines of functor code..but it looks like std::bind is of no use in this case...

Comment: @user124 I could probably figure out an alternative using `std::bind`, but it would be more complicated than what I have shown. Basically, `std::bind` makes the functor for you. Do you need an example? If so, it might have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: yeah exactly, in normal case of bind, the argument to function are the placeholders and they change, but here objects are changing and their arguments are same and function return value. So, i wish to know whether bind can be used in this case by some means. Plz do let me know if. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user124:  You don't really need to use std::bind for this.  They functor example he's given will work with C++99 standards.  You can just create a function that returns the type you need, and takes the magic_number as your input and use std::transform the same way.  Using std::bind for this would be overly complicated for what you are trying to do.